# Unterminated string literal error in var declaration

Tags: javascript

I have declared var:

```
var myid=mydata.id;    
var imgpath="https://graph.facebook.com/<?=myid ?>/picture?type=small";
```

which gives error :

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
var imgpath="https://graph.facebook.com/<br />`
```

I already have terminated it!
Where is the mitake?

full functiom:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=movies,email', function(mydata) {
            console.log(mydata.email);
           console.log(mydata.id); 
           var myid=mydata.id;
           var imgpath="https://graph.facebook.com/<?=myid ?>/picture?type=small";
           //console.log(imgpath);  ....}
```

Comment: Please hit `Ctrl+U` and see your script's output.

Comment: you have a problem with <?=myid ?>. It has some symbols which are not acceptable.

Comment: You have PHP code in your javascript...

Comment: You also don't seem to understand the different between PHP and JavaScript. They aren't interchangeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<?=myid ?>` is undefined constant which will be interpreted by PHP as string. But before it PHP will print error with few new lines.

JS don't like new lines in strings, so it produces error.

If you wanted to use previously defined JS var, you have to use it like this:

```
var imgpath = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + myid + "/picture?type=small";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var imgpath="https://graph.facebook.com/"+myid +"/picture?type=small";
```